# java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program from another java program using Runtime.getrunTime().exec

Code :

```
String java_home = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
 String[] command = {""+java_home+"/bin/java -cp -cp /sc/sug/p-lib/*  Tdesigner -cd /pr -in ing.rsp -out /scratch/sug/ng.pla -ad -stopO "};
                try {
                    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    proc.waitFor();
                    int exitCode = proc.exitValue();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

It gives me following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/net/sl/sc/jdk6/bin/java -cp /sc/sug/p-lib/*  Tdesigner -cd /pr -in ing.rsp -out /scratch/sug/ng.pla -ad -stopOnError ": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue. is it that i need to add individual jar files with -cp rather than setting the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the extra `-cp` from the command string array and use individual tokens in the array:

```
String[] command = { java_home + "/bin/java", "-cp",
   "/sc/sug/p-lib/*", "Tdesigner", "-cd", "/pr", "-in", "ing.rsp",
   "-out", "/scratch/sug/ng.pla", "-ad", "-stopO" };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use exec(String[]) you must provide the command and its arguments in separate array elements, not all in one as you have done.

Comment: String[] command = {""+java_home+"/bin/java -cp /sc/sug/p-lib/*  Tdesigner", "-cd",  "/pr", "-in", "ing.rsp",  "-out" , "/scratch/sug/ng.pla" ,"-ad", "-stopO"};    Modified the command still get the same error.:(

Comment: You still have the java -cp /sc/.../* Tdesigner as all one string, it needs to be separated.  Otherwise instead of calling java and passing it the arguments -cp etc., you are trying to run a program *called* java -cp /sc/...

Answer (score 0):

I use scala. Here is my code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array("/bin/bash", "-c", #your_command)).waitFor()
```

I think it is easy to understand for others who use java.